# How to send inforation from unity to access

Tags: c#, ms-access, unity-game-engine

An odd question.. what?

Well.. What I mean by send Information to access, is that I want to recive in my access file, information from a mobile app that I build in unity, and these is ONLY and purely for research purposes...

Is that even possible?

I tried to find Information about this subject but it seems that I'm the only one interested in those numbers...

Btw - what I need to send is numbers - floats and ints, and if It's possible, a small description of what those numbers means, if access can't tell me.

And if there is a way, how?

(Also, If i need to pay to a url or something I will do that).

Thanks in advance,

Roei Meiri.

Comment: Database is client side or server side? If server side, you need to build a web service to be the middle man. If client side, you'll need to search for a cross-platform solution as opposed to using Access. Even then I am not sure what support unity actually has for working with the local solution.

Answer (score 0):

As highlighted by [TyCobb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/359157/tycobb) and [this post](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/588527/connecting-to-access-database-via-c.html) local access to an access db is problematic without a server in the middle.

As indicated in the linked post above, using an SQLite DB is best, with JSON data second. Both have loads of plugins available to help on the asset store.